# Can I choose which properties of an item to display in a listview?

Tags: c#, listview

Say I have the following objects:

```
List<Track> Tracks;

class Track
{    
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public FileInfo SourceFile { get; set;}

    //... constructor etc
}
```

if I set a data gridview's datasource to Tracks (the list), it displays the full path of the FileInfo object. Is there an easy way of displaying a different property by default?

Thanks

Comment: If I get you right, I think binding the columns using the `DataPropertyName` property should work in this case...but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the Path property of the Binding. Here's XAML example from [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/GridViewWpf11082009182813PM/GridViewWpf.aspx).

```
<GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Authors">
   <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
   <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Age}" />
   <GridViewColumn Header="Book" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Book}" />
   <GridViewColumn Header="MVP" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Mvp}" />
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need overrride ToString() in the class FileInfo or inherit it.